# Persist constraint unique after destroy

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a users table with the unique username. When I delete the users and recreate the same users the error appears:

```
Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed
```

It seems that unique count of the username is persistent after destroy. Is there a way to remove this constraint after deleting?

I have seen in the sequelize documentation that hooks exist but I don't quite understand how to apply it

**UPDATE**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
// Connection
const { sequelize } = require('../config/sequelize');
const UserSource = require('./UserSource');

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        unique: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
    },
    place_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
}, {
    paranoid: true,
    timestamps: false,
});

User.hasMany(UserSource, { foreignKey: 'user_id', sourceKey: 'user_id'});
UserSource.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', sourceKey: 'user_id'});

module.exports = User;
```

I've also tried `paranoid: false` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you show your model definition? Are you using `paranoid: true`?

Comment: After you turned off paranoid mode and deleted a record did you see it in a DB?